# If user leave comment, print "You have already written a comment"

Tags: 7

how to show this 'You have already written a comment' if user have comment in this node -)

Thanks for any help)

Comment: You want to show it as an error message?

Comment: Just little icon with text in teaser node, what can help user understand where comment he leave and where no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function custom_cv_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
 global $user;
  if ($view_mode == 'teaser') { /* Teaser */
      $cid = db_query('SELECT cid FROM {comment} WHERE uid= :uid AND nid = :nid', array(':uid' => $user->uid, ':nid' => $node->nid))->fetch();
      if($cid) {
          $node->title = $node->title.' (Commented)';
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Comment limit](http://drupal.org/project/comment_limit) module.

> Limits how many comments a user may post on a node.
>   Adjustable on a per node type basis.
>
> This module can be handy for instance when comments are used as "Reviews" and "Ratings" for products and a user may only review and rate a product once.

Answer (score 0):

Make a small custom module that implements [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) .  If the form ID is the node comment form run a check to see if the current `global $user`has commented on this node before (you might have to write a custom function for this).  If the user has commented on the node in question disable the submit and the textarea.